# mod_rewrite in .htaccess with two rewriterules

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

it's driving me crazy i want to do some simple rewrites with htacces but can't get it work.

First redirect i want is if someone enters just server url (http://www.myserver.com) that he becomes redirected to some /var/www subfolder, this i got done by:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ ./some/application/$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^$ ./some/application/ [QSA]
```

and works ... Second step i wanted is if someone enters (http://www.myserver.com/testpage) that he becomes redirected under this url to some different subfolder of /var/www.

Tried whole load of stuff, but can't get further than 500 internal server error.
You're welcome to give me input. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are possibly getting caught out by the fact that when you add another `RewriteRule`, it will be working with a URI that has *already* been rewritten by the first two rules.  This means that if you had the following, for example:

```
RewriteRule ^testpage(/.*)?$ ./some/other/app$1 [QSA]
```

It would fail because by this point you would be passing it `/some/application/testpage`.

You can get around this issue by adding another condition to the existing rewrite:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/testpage/?       ## this is the new condition
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ ./some/application/$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^$ ./some/application/ [QSA]

## here is the new rule
RewriteRule ^testpage(/.*)?$ ./some/other/app$1 [QSA]
```

Basically unless you specify the `[L]` flag to the rule, which will stop any further rule from running, the rules are cumulative, and act on the output of any previous rules.